# How can I move the posted-on date above the post and below the entry-header?

Tags: php, hooks

The posted-on date by default appears below the post. How can I move the posted-on date above the post and below the entry-header? I'm using a child theme of Twenty Sixteen. Because the post-on date is generated after the content, I don't believe a solution is possible with css.

Comment: All prophets are on vacation now, so we want you to show us some code you used to create your child theme's `single.php` [template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post). Also, maybe you'll be interested in [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) as a starting point.

Comment: @MaxYudin, thank you for the Theme Handbook link. I have not edited index.php or single.php. That is why I did not post any code. I examined those files prior to posting my question but I could not find a way to change the position of posted-on by editing either of those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To move the posted-on date above the post and below entry-header, copy the template-parts directory with only content.php and content-single.php from themes/twentysixteen/ into your child theme. In content.php, move `twentysixteen_entry_meta();` from the entry-footer div to just above the entry-content div. This will put the posted-on date above entry-content on all the posts. Do the same for content-single.php and that places the posted-on date above entry-content on single posts.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the file that renders the section of the site from the parent to your child theme, keeping the structure the same as the parent.
Then make the code change in your child-theme copy and the theme will then use that file instead.

See here for more information on doing this:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes#Template_Files

Comment: Do you know which file renders that portion of the post? Perhaps that should have been my original question. I currently have functions.php, header.php, index.php and style.css. This particular install will not have pages only posts.

Comment: It would likely be single.php but not 100% sure on that one I'm afraid. If you give me a while I'll look for it and let you know.

Comment: thank you for your help. I looked at single.php but I didn't see a way to change the sequence of the entry header, entry content and posted-on. Also, I had hoped to make this change not only to single but on the (index.php) where all the posts are displayed. It seemed to me that I would have to go to a file not on the root level (something other than index.php or single.php).